# remove the mean over multiple measurements

Tags: normalization, definition, reporting, centering

I have a set of multiple measurements for each subject (i.e. each subject is assessed several days).

For each set of measurements (several days of the same subject) I am calculating the mean value of the measurements and I am substracting it to the original measurement values.

I am doing it for each subject.
Which operation (I am interested in the 2 words name) am I performing? (normalization, centering...)

Can I write something like this in my report: *"Temperature and galvanic skin response data were first cleaned from missing values and outliers and then, for each subject, were centered across the mean over multiple days."*

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is called centering.

Comment: Thanks! Is it correct (undestandable) then my statement?

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it, perhaps by discussing its implications for the correctness of the OP's statement? You can also turn it into a comment.

Comment: @gung there's really nothing to add. Simple question, simple answer. If it's flagged, it's flagged.

Comment: You could explain the implications of your point for whether the OP can write their given statement in their report, eg.

Comment: @gung The problem lies in the question.  Questions that ask for the names of things tend not to fit our format well: as linksys says, they really need only a one or two word answer.